# Java socket server cannot receive many data at the same time, how to make java socket server accept data at the same time?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

my java socket server cannot accept more than one data at the same time in one client

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
            ServerSocket ss = null;
            try {
                ss = new ServerSocket(9000);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                while(true) {
                    System.out.println("Waiting Transaction ..");
                    Socket clientSocket = ss.accept();
                    InetAddress inet = clientSocket.getInetAddress();
                    try{
                        while (clientSocket.getInputStream().available() == 0) {
                            Thread.sleep(100L);
                        }
                        byte[] data;
                        int bytes;
                        data = new byte[clientSocket.getInputStream().available()];
                        bytes = clientSocket.getInputStream().read(data,0,data.length);
                        String dataDB = new String(data, 0, bytes, "UTF-8");
                        System.out.println("received data\n time : "+ new Date() +"length data : " + dataDB.length());
                        System.out.println(dataDB);
                        String dataFrom = getFromServer(dataDB);
                        clientSocket.getOutputStream().write(dataFrom.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    }catch (BindException be){
                        be.printStackTrace();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally {
                        clientSocket.close();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    ss.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        t1.start();
```

i try using thread but it not working, this code only accept the first data otherwise anoter data will be decline. how to server accept many data at the same time?

Comment: You need to put inner try block code inside a loop so that it keep listening for next bytes whenever available, this way it just accepts one time and thread body completes, also you are accepting new socket in while loop, so your loop will wait there only until new client join it and till then it won't reach your byte reading code.

Comment: @code_mechanic inner loop like what that I have to create inside this code, would you please give an example?

Comment: 'Not working' is not a problem description, but this is a classic misuse of `available()`. Remove the spin loop before the first `read()`, and use a fixed size buffer for receiving. Don't ignore the possibility that `read()` returns -1.

Comment: @code_mechanic Unclear what you're saying. It wouldn't make any sense to try to read input from a client that hadn't been accepted yet.

Comment: @user207421 Yes, that was unclear, so I have added as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me tell you how I did it, while playing around with sockets, so I created a SocketServer class

```
public class Server {
    public static final Integer port = 9000;
    private final ServerSocket server;
    private final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    private final AtomicInteger idGenerator = new AtomicInteger(0);

    public Server() throws IOException {
        this.server = new ServerSocket(port);
    }

    public void start() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                Worker worker = new Worker(idGenerator.incrementAndGet(), server.accept());
                service.execute(worker);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now every time, a client joins, I create a worker thread and submit it to `ExecutorService` (Executor service has pool of threads and run the passed worker by allocating a thread to it, you can read about it).

The worker class looks like this

```
public class Worker implements Runnable {
    private final Socket client;
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public Worker(Integer id, Socket client) {
        this.id = id;   //Ignore it, it was for logging purpose, how many joined
        this.client = client;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        listenClientMessages();

        closeConnection();
    }

    private void listenClientMessages() {
        final int MAX_INPUT = 1024;
        int read;
        try (InputStream is = client.getInputStream()) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[MAX_INPUT];
            while ((read = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
                String line = new String(buf, 0, read);
                log.info(line);

                if (line.equals("bye")) break;
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void closeConnection() {
        try{
            client.close();
        }catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So, you can see, I am reading bytes in while look

```
            byte[] buf = new byte[MAX_INPUT];
            while ((read = is.read(buf)) != -1) {
                String line = new String(buf, 0, read);
                log.info(line);

                if (line.equals("bye")) break;
            }
```

that's why when MAX_INPUT or less is processed, it would wait from client to send next input.

Let me know if it helps.

**Edit:** As commented by @user207421 in comments, `closeConnection` function is redundant as inputstream is closed with try-wit-resources block above in `listenClientMessages` function, so it is not needed.

Comment: The `closeConnection()` method is redundant given the try-with-resources.

Comment: Won't that close only the stream and will socket object be closed when thread dies? I was confused about this part.

Comment: Closing either the input or the output stream of a socket closes the other stream and the socket. See the Javadoc.

Comment: @code_mechanic thank for your answer, but actually that i mean how to receive many data at same time like thread, because in my code server that i created it just accept one data who came first and the next data will be decline. thankyou

Comment: what you mean by many data? can you give an example? what is sent and what is received?

Comment: @code_mechanic for example client send two or more data at the same time, so my socket server only receive the data who came first and the second data can't receive, so my question is, how to receive many data in server socket at the same time? thankyou

Comment: You are thinking that "many data" is coming in one chunk on the server, but it is not, you may not receive all bytes in one go, you would have to wait for, when next bytes come, so when you check that if bytes are available, it will receive few bytes and your for loop will end, and you would just read that, ignoring rest. As pointed into comments also, first do not use `available`, you need to wait until all bytes arrived and read them in that loop like I am doing in `listenClientMessages` function.

Comment: @code_mechanic thank you for helping me, now my server is working.